# What is the common project structure for spring-boot including both front-end and back-end

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to setup a web-based application and the first thing I need to decide is about the project structure. Spring-boot can bootstrap a nested web container which makes development process muse easier. But I want to get some help on whether I need to put front-end code(javascript, html, css, etc) and back-end code (mostly spring-mvc based code) into one project. And let spring to boot both of them. If so, what may the project structure look like?

Comment: Answers should be given.